# JavaScript AddEventListener Returns null in console

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, addeventlistener

am new to JavaScript and recently started learning the DOM.
In my code, I tried adding a click event listener to a button as shown below:

```
var p1Btn = document.querySelector("#p1");
p1Btn.addEventListener("onclick", function(){
"use strict";
alert("P1 BUTTON CLICKED!!!"); 
});
```

but I keep getting this error in console,

```
VM86:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at <anonymous>:2:10
```

on further inspection, I find that it is actually pointing to this line in my code block:

```
p1Btn.addEventListener("onclick", function(){
```

Could someone kindly point out to me why this is being highlighted and what the best way to write JavaScript code is. Thanks.

Have added the full html code as suggested, do take a look:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DOM</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

    <h1>0 to 0</h1>

    <p>Playing to: 5</p>

    <input type="number">

    <button id="p1">Player 1</button>
    <button id="p2">Player 2</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file is included now:

```
var p1Btn = document.querySelector("#p1");
p1Btn.addEventListener("onclick", function(){
"use strict";
alert("P1 BUTTON CLICKED!!!");
});
```

Comment: You must be overlooking something and `var p1Btn = document.querySelector("#p1");` is returning null. Is the code block to add the listener called at init time or dynamically? Post your entire code.

Comment: The event you seek is ["click"](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click), not "onclick".

Comment: I have tried both "click" and "onclick", will post the code now. Thanks

Comment: @AnandRajput—there is no "onclick" event, so even if you solve the null issue, it won't work. Use "click". *onclick* is the related HTML attribute and DOM property name.

Comment: Your code as posted works. Voting to close as can't reproduce.

Comment: @RobG, kindly help me understand the situation, closing now won't help me in anyway.

Comment: @AnandRajput—your question should include information and preferably minimal code to replicate the issue. You haven't done that. Your code as posted works (if the event name is changed to "click"). Until you can post an example here that reproduces  `document.querySelector("#p1")` returning null, the only help you'll get are guesses.

Answer (score 0):

use click event instead of onclick.

```
document.getElementById("p1").addEventListener("click", function(){
"use strict";
alert("P1 BUTTON CLICKED!!!"); 
});
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmz186cx/1/)

if you are facing 'Cannot read property...' error then you can wrap your js code inside $(document).ready jquery or in plain js like.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //put js code here.
});
```

Comment: The event name is an issue, but *p1Btn* is null, changing the event name will not fix that.

Comment: have tried ur suggestion, still showing same error in console

Comment: yes, it shows p1Btn as null in console, any fix to that?

Comment: then you must be loading js code before html. putting it in document ready will solve the problem. check the fiddle for more.

Comment: @KamalJoshi, the js code is loaded at bottom of body, any better place to keep it?

Comment: no bottom of the body is fine. have you tried this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gmz186cx/1/